# What's the rationale for Convert.ToBoolean() taking a bool parameter?

Tags: c#, boolean, clr

Why is it implemented? It doesn't do any conversion so it serves no purpose. Per the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hhf28xt(v=vs.110).aspx) "*Returns the specified Boolean value; no actual conversion is performed.*"

Comment: It's the same reasoning as for [ToByte(byte)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c9st3bt(v=vs.110).aspx). One example of usefulness could be generic methods.

Comment: This overload can be useful in cases when type of input parameter is unknown (`dynamic` for example) then you simply can use `Convert.ToBoolean(dynamicValue)`

Comment: @Fabio I think dynamic is indeed the only valid reason for that. For general unknown type `Convert.ToBoolean(object)` will be called, but for dynamic it will indeed choose the correct overload. Maybe you should post that as answer.

Comment: @Evk But the egg was born before the hen here... :-) `Convert.ToBoolean(bool)` is .NET 1.1, while `dynamic` is .NET 4.0

Comment: @xanatos yes, but we can say that was just a great planning!

Comment: @Evk Great and planning aren't two words that I'll ever put in .NET 1.1 :-) (the whole no-generics that generated so many problems and duplications) Let's say that as written `Convert.To*` is very complete and symmetrical... For me the whole class is nearly useless, but once a year I have to use it (the simple fact that there are no `TryConvert` is enough to classify it as badly written)

Comment: There are more useless methods there by the way, like `Convert.ToDateTime(bool)` which just always throws exception. So I guess they just took all types that implemented IConvertible at that time and duplicated that interface methods for all of them.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion of poor planning. Fabio that is a valid case but as mentioned the timing doesn't explain why it was put there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Overload of `Convert.ToBoolean` with `bool` as parameter can be useful in cases where type of input parameter is unknown

```
dynamic receivedValue = true; // or 23 (int)
var isTrue = Convert.ToBoolean(receivedValue);
```

Above code will use overload of `ToBoolean` based on actual type of given value.

Comment: I don't think this is true. dynamic is simply refers to System.Object with compiler tricks.